# How to correctly write regular expression to match ASCII control chars

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to to create a regular expression in elisp (in the standard 'read' form) to match extended ASCII chars the same as PCRE does:

```
^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$
```

So, I'm currently сonfused about `\x7f-\xff`. Is there a way to set a range using something like \x*hh*?

Comment: I think the answer depends on whether you're matching against unibyte or multibyte strings. Do you think À (which is undefined in ASCII, 0xC0 in latin-1 and Unicode, but encoded as 0xC380 in UTF-8) falls into the range 0x7F-0xFF?

Comment: I think so. At least PCRE matched À as a char in 0x7F-0xFF range. I need the same behavior for standard Elisp regular expression.

Comment: And as I can see `À` is defined in ASCII: https://www.ascii-code.com. 0xC0 is between 0x7F and 0xFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`-ÿ`** instead of `\x7f-\xff`. That first character, which StackExchange prints as a space, is **`DEL`**, which has codepoint 127 (decimal), #o177 (octal), and #x7f (hexadecimal).

That is, you can just *insert the characters themselves* in the regexp pattern.

One way to input such characters is to use **`C-x 8 RET`**. To search for any char in the range `\x7f` through `\xff` you would type this at the `C-M-s` prompt (without the spaces):

`[ C-x 8 RET # x 7 f - C-x 8 RET # x f f ]`